# Flutter firebase_admob failing to load ads on iOS production

Tags: firebase, flutter, admob, ads

I have 3 apps that use older versions of firebase_admob (0.9.3), firebase_core (0.4.4) and firebase_analytics (5.0.11) that show ads accordingly.

Now I've updated one of them to the latest version of those packages and production ads on iOS outputs the message "failed to load ad" on debug.

These are the latest versions:

- firebase_admob: ^0.10.0+2
- firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1
- firebase_analytics: ^6.0.2

Test ads show both on android and iOS. Production ads show only on Android. For what I've seen, if test ads are shown, implementation is correct.

I've also added theses keys to Info.plist:

```
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>ca-app-pub-xxxxx-my-app-id-xxxxx</string>
<key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

On AdMob dashboard I can see I get ad requests, but there are no impressions at all.

There's no more information on the debug output so I cannot make sense out of it.

This is the output from Xcode 12.0.1 (running on a physical device):

```
<Google> To get test ads on this device, set: GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = @[ @"b15cb21bc27c0f3484e5b7c4df41e429" ];
FirebaseAdMobPlugin <warning> adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: Request Error: No ad to show. (MobileAd <FLTBannerAd: 0x281bec4e0> PENDING mobileAdId:46290759 for: <GADBannerView: 0x12ff916c0; frame = (0 0; 320 50); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x283fd38a0>>)
flutter: BannerAd event is MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad
```

That's strange, because if I set this test device id, I do get test ads on the physical device. But on the other apps I don't get this message and in fact I get real ads.

Comment: Try use `admob_flutter` instead. Personally I think it is better than `firebase_admob`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I've discovered that admob will NOT show ads on ios physical device before app is published to app store, since app does not have a content rating yet.

Implementation was indeed correct.

Edit: My app is published on App Store for 2 weeks now and I still get NO impressions, despite getting many requests. Admob is still not able to link to app store. I'm hoping it will start getting impressions as soon as I can link.

Edit2: After 16 days, admob could list my app and 10 hours after linking the app started getting impressions.

Comment: I have the same problem, my app is new (published 3 days ago on the AppStore) and by iOS I receive requests but not impressions. Obviously the app is not yet connected in admob to the AppStore because Admob doesn't find it at the moment. In your opinion, should I just wait for the app to be linkable and I will start getting impressions?

Comment: @diegocom definitely. Something has changed inside admob and now it only impresses ads after linking. My previous apps hadn't needed it but now it seems it's the only way.

Comment: Did you have to link it through App settings -> App Store option?
I am not getting any impressions either. What did you do to fix it?

Comment: This answer is pretty much it guys, trust me, if your test keys work and you're sure your keys are correct it's just a waiting game. I waited for 16 days before Admob could see my ad to link. After I linked I thought I was gonna see ads but no, I had to wait another two days after linking. So please don't be discouraged.

Comment: Same here. Took nearly 3 weeks for admob to list the app in the App Store to link

Comment: Admob has been abandoned (for iOS at least). No support available (when you try an error message appears). I'm stuck for more than 2 months, and no ads showing on iOS and no app linking on the admob console (can't find my own app on store) !